# Are clojure function cyclic dependencies specifically disallowed by design, or is it just a reader behaviour?

Tags: function, clojure, cyclic-dependency

If I do the following in clojure

```
(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1b (- a 1) )))

(defn sub1b [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1a (- a 1) )))

(println (sub1a 10))
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: sub1b in this context
```

But if I do the following:

```
(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (- a 1)))

(defn sub1b [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (- a 1)))

(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1b (- a 1) )))

(defn sub1b [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1a (- a 1) )))

(println (sub1a 10))
```

It runs just fine.

Is this by design, or just a function of the way the Clojure reader works?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do

```
(declare sub1a sub1b)
```

'declare' is specifically meant to create a var with no bindings for making forward declarations.

One you declared the names:

```
(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1b (- a 1) )))

(defn sub1b [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    true (sub1a (- a 1) )))

(println (sub1a 10))
```

Also the idomatic way to specify the default condition in cond (for clojure) is using the :else clause. This is a bit different from Common Lisp which uses T (for True). So your previous code can be rewritten as:

```
(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    :else (sub1b (- a 1) )))

...
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is as posted by rkrishnan.

As for this part of the question:

> Is this by design, or just a function of the way the Clojure reader works?

Actually this is nothing to do with the Clojure reader -- it's because the compiler resolves symbols to Vars immediately upon encountering them (in those positions where they would need "ultimately" to be resolved to a Var, as opposed to places where they name locals, are quoted or passed to a special form or a macro, of course). This makes sense for reasons of efficiency: knowing which Var a symbol refers to at compile time makes it possible to generate code which needs not resolve symbols at runtime (it still normally needs to look up the *values* of the Vars, but not the Vars themselves). If you really wanted to, you could have your code resolve symbols at runtime:

```
(defn sub1a [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    :else ((resolve 'sub1b) (- a 1) )))

(defn sub1b [a]
  (cond
    (= a 0) 0
    :else ((resolve 'sub1a) (- a 1) )))

(println (sub1a 10))

; prints 0 and returns nil
```

This does, however, cause a certain degradation in performance which is hardly ever justified in real code, thus Clojure makes you be explicit about it if you *really* think this is what you want.